# Classifying two lists and arrange accordingly in python

Tags: python

I'm working with 2 lists looks like this:

```
list_a = [x,y,z,.....]  
list_b = [xa,xb,xc,xd,xe,ya,yb,yc,yd,za,zb,zc,zd,ze,zf]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, to make more lists while arranging the data like following:

```
list_x = [x,xa,xb,xc,xd,xe]  
list_y = [y,ya,yb,yc,yd]  
list_z = [z,za,zb,zc,zd,ze,zf]
```

Now if I use loops like:

```
final_list=[]
for item in list_a:
    for value in list_b:
    if value[0] == item:
        print item, value
```

It filters the data but can not reach the desired format.
Could you guys please give some valuable comment on this.
thank you

Comment: and what have you tried to format your result?

Comment: As I have tried using nested loops I'm getting it like: [x,xa][x,xb][x,xc][x,xd] and so on. I have no clear idea how can I create list list as per items in `list_a` and `append/extend` to get the desired format. Suggestions would be very helpful regarding that.

Comment: read a tutorial dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% about this formatting, but you could use a list of lists.

```
list_a = ["x","y","z"]  
list_b = ["xa","xb","xc","xd","xe","ya","yb","yc","yd","za","zb","zc","zd","ze","zf"]  
final_list = []
for item in list_a:
    item_list = [item]
    for value in list_b:
        if value[0] == item:
            item_list.append(value)
    final_list.append(item_list)
print final_list
```

It returns
    [['x', 'xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'xd', 'xe'], ['y', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc', 'yd'], ['z', 'za', 'zb', 'zc', 'zd', 'ze', 'zf']]

Comment: Thanks for a versatile answer. People put all specific ans, I jst wanted an opinion analogous to my data. It helped.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

```
list_a = ['x','y','z']  
list_b = ['xa','xb','xc','xd','xe','ya','yb','yc','yd','za','zb','zc','zd','ze','zf']  

print [[x for x in list_b if x.startswith(y)] for y in list_a]
```

Output :

```
[['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'xd', 'xe'], ['ya', 'yb', 'yc', 'yd'], ['za', 'zb', 'zc', 'zd', 'ze', 'zf']]
```

Or more quite :

```
print [(y,[x for x in list_b if x.startswith(y)]) for y in list_a]
```

Output :

```
[('x', ['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'xd', 'xe']), ('y', ['ya', 'yb', 'yc', 'yd']), ('z', ['za', 'zb', 'zc', 'zd', 'ze', 'zf'])]
```

Comment: Not quite what he wanted but also ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
list_a = ['x','y','z']
list_b = ['xa','xb','xc','xd','xe','ya','yb','yc','yd','za','zb','zc','zd','ze','zf']
print [(key, [_ for _ in list_b if key == _[0]]) for key in list_a]
```

It gives you a list of tuples with the first entry being the single letter and the second being the list.

Or you do it without tuples like this:

```
print [[key] + [_ for _ in list_b if key == _[0]] for key in list_a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow a functional approach by using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [46]: from itertools import groupby

In [47]: from operator import itemgetter

In [48]: list_b = ['xa','xb','xc','xd','xe','ya','yb','yc','yd','za','zb','zc','zd','ze','zf']

In [49]: [[prefix] + list(group) for prefix, group in groupby(list_b, key=itemgetter(0))]
Out[49]: 
[['x', 'xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'xd', 'xe'],
 ['y', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc', 'yd'],
 ['z', 'za', 'zb', 'zc', 'zd', 'ze', 'zf']]
```

It is important to note that if `list_b` is not ordered, the argument passed to `groupby()` should be `sorted(list_b)` instead.

As a side note, you could get rid of the module `operator` by simply changing the optional argument `key=itemgetter(0)` to `key=lambda s: s[0]`.